# Scrapy: using multiple image fields, store results

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am using scrapy to capture several images. I save them in separate fields. Because of dependencies with other systems, I do not want all the images results (url, path, checksum) stored in one field.

- image_url1
- image_url2

The results (url, path, checksum), are stored in;

- images1
- images2

I finally have it working where it downloads 2 pictures.
The results for the image_url1 is stored in images1. Only it doesn't store the results for image_url2 in images2. I don't know how I make clear that the results for image_url2 should be stored in images2. If I now run the following code, it tries to put the 2 results (url, path, checksum) together (results of image_url1 and image_url2 behind each other separated by a space). It cannot insert that field into MySQL so that fails.

```
class GooutImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_url1']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)
        for image_url in item['image_url2']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)
```

I already made the following edit in settings;

```
IMAGES_URLS_FIELD = 'image_url1'
IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD = 'images1'
```

I can't find anything how to work with multiple image fields.

*** Edit/solution after feedback
After the suggestion to do this in item_completed, I come up with the following;

```
class GooutImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        if item['image_url1']:
            for image_url in item['image_url1']:
                yield scrapy.Request(image_url)
        if item['image_url2']:
            for image_url in item['image_url2']:
                yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        for download_status, result in results:
            if result['url'] == item['image_url1'][0]:
                item['images1'] = result['path']
            if result['url'] ==  item['image_url2'][0]:
                item['images2'] = result['path']
        return item
```

Don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it works. Feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [item_completed()](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline.item_completed) method is what does this storing, so that's what you'll need to override.

You will need to know where to store the data though, so you'll probably want to add that information to the `meta` dict of the request you create in `get_media_requests()`.